# Remove Springiness From SCNPhysicsBallSocketJoint

Tags: ios, swift, game-physics, scenekit, scnnode

I'm building my first app in **Swift** and it's based on the *bimini ring toss game* you see in bars with a ring attached to a string from the ceiling.  I'm using a SCNPhysicsBallSocketJoint to connect a bunch of small spheres to act like a string/rope.  I've got some early results that are good but the spheres are way too springy in their connection. The repo is [here](https://github.com/ChrisFlannagan/iOS-Bimini-Ring-Toss/blob/master/BiminiRingToss/GameViewController.swift) if you want to run it yourself but here's the code for connecting the spheres.

```
/** Generate our rope links **/
    var cnt:Float = 0.0
    var previousLink: SCNNode = ropeObject.getRope()
    var links :[SCNNode] = [SCNNode]()
    while cnt < 4.0 {
        let link = ropeObject.getLink( y: Float(cnt) )
        links.append(link)

        let joint = SCNPhysicsBallSocketJoint(
            bodyA: link.physicsBody!,
            anchorA: SCNVector3(x: -0.05, y: -0.05, z: -0.05),
            bodyB: previousLink.physicsBody!,
            anchorB: SCNVector3(x: 0.05, y: 0.05, z: 0.05)
        )
        scnScene.physicsWorld.addBehavior(joint)

        previousLink = link
        cnt += 0.1
    }
```

Comment: Anything new regarding springiness reduction?

Answer (score 0):

Try to significantly increase `mass` property of your spheres, it will result less springiness.

Also, Chris, thank you so much for posting this project in your blog, it helped me a lot with my rope-like object.